# Active Directory Integrated DNS Records Deletion by System

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

I have an issue where records are 'disappearing' from my primary DNS zone. The client records for these devices are static entries. The entries replicate correctly but get randomly removed. I have tracked the edits back to the PDC with auditing. Where do I go from here?

Here is the setup:

- 4 Win7 clients connected through VPN to my domain.
- Three Server 2012R2 DCs; Two at my local site and one on Azure.
- DNS is integrated into Active Directory.
- DNS Scavenging is **off.**
- "Delete record when stale" is unchecked.

From my searching online I have found [an article about disappearing DNS records](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/windowsserver/en-US/4ba67b5e-18e1-4351-8e06-97a8a59ac1d7/static-dns-records-disappearing). Used ASDIEdit to check the `Partitions` in the `Configuration` and was able to load the `DomainDnsZones` and `ForestDnsZones` as well. I also [setup auditing on the DNS entries](http://blogs.technet.com/b/networking/archive/2011/08/17/tracking-dns-record-deletion.aspx). This enabled me to track what was making the edits...

> Subject:
>
> Security ID:       SYSTEM
>
> Account Name:      SYSTEM
>
> Account Domain:        NT AUTHORITY
>
> Logon ID:      0x44936
>
> Directory Service:
>
> Name:  example.com
>
> Type:  Active Directory Domain Services
>
> Object:
>
> DN:    DC=computer_name,DC=example.com,cn=MicrosoftDNS,DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=example,DC=com
>
> GUID:  DC=computer_name,DC=example.com,CN=MicrosoftDNS,DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=example,DC=com
>
> Class: dnsNode
>
> Attribute:
>
> LDAP Display Name: dNSTombstoned
>
> Syntax (OID):  2.5.5.8
>
> Value: TRUE

Great so I know my DC made the edit. That doesn't tell me why and leaves me stuck. Any suggestions?

Update:
It appears after changing the Zones Dynamic update settings from `Unsecure & Secure` to `Secure only` the deletions still occur.

I am looking into the possibility of a replication issue at the moment. When I update the PDC static entry, it replicates fine to the second DC but does not replicate to the DC in a seperate site.

Comment: When you say disappearing, do you mean someone is deleting them?  Or something?

Comment: @Brad Bouchard: OP sees records disappearing and checks the logs. Logs point to the DC making the edits. See http://blogs.technet.com/b/isrpfeplat/archive/2010/09/23/dns-scavenging-internals-or-what-is-the-dnstombstoned-attribute-for-ad-integrated-zones-dstombstoneinterval-dnstombstoned.aspx for more information on this. Obvious answer would be to disable DNS scavenging, but OP says this is already off.

Comment: Are the systems in question being assigned an IP by DHCP?  If so, is the DHCP server configured to delete the DNS records when the lease is up?

Comment: Other possibility is that one of the DNS servers still has scavenging turned on.  Note there are scavenging settings at the zone level, and also at the server level.  Make sure it is disabled everywhere on all servers.  Check the Event Viewer of every server for Event ID 2501 to confirm scavenging is not running.

Comment: Do you allow non-secure dynamic updates to your Zone?  If so, it is possible that something on the client side is messing with DNS.

Comment: @msemack The IP is static for these clients. The DHCP server is configured to delete records but the records are assigned to the VPN server not directly to the clients. Currently I am allowing non-secure DNS updates. Ironically due to some Microsoft troubleshooting... I'll return it to secure and see if that solves it.

Comment: @msemack The record deletion usually occurs with a few hours of creation. With the dynamic updates set to Secure Only the problem seems solved. If you make your comments an answer, I will mark it as such. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was given in the comments by msemack. The issue was due to the Dynamic Updates setting on the zone set to `Unsecured and Secure` rather than `Secure only`.

Answer (score 1):

Enable the Advanced view (**View** -> **Advanced**) and make sure that **Delete this record when it becomes stale** is not checked in the **Properties** dialog for the record.

Active Directory manages A and AAAA records for Domain Controllers automatically. This seems to have higher priority than the checkbox. Microsoft has a [knowledge base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2023004%20%27%27Steps%20to%20avoid%20registering%20unwanted%20NIC%28s%29%20in%20DNS%20on%20a%20Mulithomed%20Domain%20Controller%27%27) that describes how you can disable this behaviour. Again, this is only relevant if the affected records belong to a DC.

[This article](http://msmvps.com/blogs/acefekay/archive/2010/12/09/dns-records-disappearing-and-dns-auditing.aspx%20%27%27DNS%20Records%20Disappearing%20and%20DNS%20Auditing%27%27) also lists some possible causes for the problem you are describing.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to mention that setting is unchecked in my post. I'll add that now.

Comment: I changed my answer. Are the records by any chance records for DCs? If not, then I would have to Google this myself as well.

Comment: No just happening with Win7 clients.

Comment: I found an article that lists some possible causes.

Comment: Yes, I have worked through that blog as well. Scavenging isn't on, there are no duplicate DNS zones and I performed the suggested Auditing. Its working but I don't know what to do with the information that 'SYSTEM' is deleting my DNS records.